# get category name from products 'reports/product_collection'

Tags: magento-1.8, reports, product-collection

I've to list the best selling products and their category name. For this I'd used

```
$_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
        ))
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

and for getting individual product:

```
foreach ($_products as $_product) {
//code need to be added here
}
```

but I'm not getting any way around to get the category name from `$_product`.

I've tried

```
$_product->getCollection()->getCategoryIds();
```

but my script dies and do not execute further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not technically a product collection of type `catalog/product`, what you need to do is:

```
$_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
    ))
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
foreach ($_products as $_product){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    $category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($category_ids as $category_id){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
        <!-- do what you want to with the category here --> 
    }
}
```

EDIT: as per comment, to limit the collection size:

```
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
    ))
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
$_products->getSelect()->limit(5); //or whatever integer you want
```

Comment: how can I add limit to `$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')`?